# Unable to send an email through contact form in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Having a contact form but not able to send an email through contact form in codeigniter PHP.Here is my code.Not getting any error messages and not getting any emails if i am filing the form and sending the request through contact form then.tried with changing the code it is redirecting to failure condition displaying as "failure"

controller:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname','First Name' , 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Mobile Number','required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text','Description','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject','Description','required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
        {   
        $data['mainpage']='contact';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
        }

    else
    {
        //echo "hi";
        //get the form data
        $name = $this->input->post('fullname');
        $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
        $description = $this->input->post('text');
        $subject=$this->input->post('subject');         

        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'email@gmail.com';

        $config=Array(
    'protocol'=> 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //smtp host name
    'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
    'smtp_user' => 'gmail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'PASSword1@3', //$from_email password
    'mailtype' =>'html',
    'newline'  =>"\r\n",
    'crlf' =>"\r\n",
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $message            = array();


    $message[] = 'Username  :  '.trim($name).' ';
    $message[] = 'Phone Number :  '.trim($phone).' ';
    $message[] = 'Description :  '.trim($description).' ';
    $message = implode(PHP_EOL, $message);
    //send mail
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->from($from_email);
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
            if ($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "sent";
            //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
           // redirect('welcome');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failure";
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class ="contactus">
                    <div class="contactname">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control names" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="FullName" >    
                        <?php echo form_error('fullname', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="contactemail">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <?php echo form_error('email', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>                         
                    </div>
                    <div class="contactsubject">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control subjects" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="contactphone">
                        <input id="phone" type="tel">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control phones" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile">
                    </div>
                    <div class="contactmessage">
                        <textarea id="text" name="text" class="textarea"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>                         
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="contactpagecaptchas">
                            <img src="/captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" class="contactpagecaptchass" id='captchaimg'/>
                            <p class="change"><a href="javascript: refreshCaptcha();" class="clickto">click to change</a></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contactcaptcha">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" placeholder="Captcha" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;border: none;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success contact1">Submit</button>                 
                </div>
```

Comment: You have to set access for less trusted apps in your Gmail account also.

Comment: Not getting you not only for gmail it is not working for comapny mail ids as well

Comment: ANy one who can solve my problem

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand what you want to say in above comment.. @user8001297

Comment: @Nidhi I am unable to send email it is going failure statement and printing as "failure" email is not working

Comment: @Nidhi I am unable to send email it is going failure statement and printing as "failure" email is not working

Comment: Are you follow this steps?1.Login to your Gmail account
2.Click on MyAccount from Google Apps
3.Click on 'Signing in to Google' from left panel
4.And Turn on 'Allow less secure apps' from bottom of page

Comment: @Nidhi solved thank you

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of [`from()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::from) must be email address. If you like add name, pass it as second parameter. Try following `from()`:

```
$from_email = 'yourfrom@example.com'; //fill with valid email that authorized in your email host
$this->email->from($from_email, $name);
```

I can't find `set_newline()` in codeigniter documentation. Maybe worked if remove it!

Comment: the person who is filling the contact form from his email the mail should go to the email mentioned in "To"

Comment: If you want to use gmail and your `smtp_user` is **YYY@gmail.com**, so your from field must be **YYY@gmail.com**, because gmail check it! `$this->email->from('YYY@gmail.com', 'YYY');`. Are you try it?

Comment: i have the same format which i posted above for other section it is working fine but in contact us it is not working